# python multiprocessing module: strange behaviour and processor load when using Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu-usage, python-multiprocessing, ubuntu-server

I'm using Python's multiprocessing lib to speed up some code (least squares fitting with scipy).

It works fine on 3 different machines, but it shows a strange behaviour on a 4th machine.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import time
import parmap
from multiprocessing import Pool

p0 = [1., 1., 0.5]

def f(p, xx):
    return p[0]*np.exp(-xx ** 2 / p[1] ** 2) + p[2]

def errorfunc(p, xx, yy):
    return f(p, xx) - yy

def do_fit(yy, xx):
    return least_squares(errorfunc, p0[:], args=(xx, yy))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create data
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
    y = []
    np.random.seed(42)
    for i in range(1000):
        y.append(f([np.random.rand(1) * 10, np.random.rand(1), 0.], x) + np.random.rand(len(x)))

    # fit without multiprocessing
    t1 = time.time()
    for y_data in y:
        p1 = least_squares(errorfunc, p0[:], args=(x, y_data))
    t2 = time.time()
    print t2 - t1

    # fit with multiprocessing lib
    times = []
    for p in range(1,13):
        my_pool = Pool(p)
        t3 = time.time()
        results = parmap.map(do_fit, y, x, pool=my_pool)
        t4 = time.time()
        times.append(t4-t3)
        my_pool.close()
    print times
```

For the 3 machines where it works, it speeds up roughly in the expected way. E.g. on my i7 laptop it gives:

```
[4.92650294303894, 2.5883090496063232, 1.7945551872253418, 1.629533052444458, 
1.4896039962768555, 1.3550388813018799, 1.1796400547027588, 1.1852478981018066, 
1.1404039859771729, 1.2239141464233398, 1.1676840782165527, 1.1416618824005127]
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10, Python 2.7.6, numpy 1.11.0 and scipy 0.17.0.
I tested it on another Ubuntu machine, a Dell PowerEdge R210 with similar results and on a MacBook Pro Retina (here with Python 2.7.11, and same numpy and scipy versions).

The computer that causes issues is a PowerEdge R710 (two hexcores) running Ubuntu 15.10, Python 2.7.11 and same numpy and scipy version as above.
However, I don't observe any speedup. Times are around 6 seconds, no matter what poolsize I use. In fact, it is slightly better for a poolsize of 2 and gets worse for more processes.

**`htop` shows that somehow more processes get spawned than I would expect.**

E.g. on my laptop `htop` shows one entry per process (which matches the poolsize) and eventually each process shows 100% CPU load.

On the PowerEdge R710 I see about 8 python processes for a poolsize of 1 and about 20 processes for a poolsize of 2 etc. each of which shows 100% CPU load.

I checked BIOS settings of the R710 and I couldn't find anything unusual.
What should I look for?

EDIT:
Answering to the comment, I used another simple script. Surprisingly this one seems to 'work' for all machines:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import math
import numpy as np

def f_np(x):
    return x**np.sin(x)+np.fabs(np.cos(x))**np.arctan(x)

def f(x):
    return x**math.sin(x)+math.fabs(math.cos(x))**math.atan(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "#pool", ", numpy", ", pure python"
    for p in range(1,9):
        pool = Pool(processes=p)
        np.random.seed(42)
        a = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
        t1 = time.time()
        for i in range(5):
            pool.map(f_np, a)
        t2 = time.time()
        for i in range(5):
            pool.map(f, range(1000000))
        print p, t2-t1, time.time()-t2
        pool.close()
```

gives:

```
#pool , numpy , pure python
1 1.34186911583 5.87641906738
2 0.697530984879 3.16030216217
3 0.470160961151 2.20742988586
4 0.35701417923 1.73128080368
5 0.308979988098 1.47339701653
6 0.286448001862 1.37223601341
7 0.274246931076 1.27663207054
8 0.245123147964 1.24748778343
```

on the machine that caused the trouble. There are no more threads (or processes?) spawned than I would expect.

It looks like numpy is not the problem, but as soon as I use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` the issue arises.

Using on `htop` on the processes shows a lot of `sched_yield()` calls which I don't see if I don't use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` and which I also don't see on my laptop even when using `least_squares`.

Comment: Since you're using `htop`, try selecting each of the 8 Python processes on the bad machine and pressing `s` for `strace`.  See what each process is doing with that 100% CPU time.  Also, try a simpler test program which doesn't use Numpy at all.

Comment: I edited my original post. I used the more complex example in the first place because it is more close to my final problem.

Comment: Let's try to figure out where those processes are spawned, shall we?  You can launch your program under a debugger, e.g. `gdb --args python yourscript.py`... then `break fork` to stop when a new process is created, then see what's doing the forking.  It might be the underlying C or Fortran routines inside Scipy.  See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2088), there is an issue when OpenBLAS is used together with joblib.

Similar issues occur when MKL is used (see [here](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/138)).
The solution given here, also worked for me:
Adding

```
import os
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
```

at the beginning of my python script solves the issue.